# Not getting data with right conditions?

Tags: select, abap, opensql

In select statement i gave right conditions but not getting data back.

When i try from se16n with these conditions it turns me one row but when i try in a program with select statement it turns me empty internal table. Here is the sample code.

gt_tcurr is an internal table that contains kurst fcurr tcurr gdatu ukurs components.

```
SELECT kurst fcurr tcurr gdatu ukurs
    INTO TABLE gt_tcurr
    FROM tcurr
    WHERE kurst = p_kurst    " as M
      AND gdatu = p_budat    " as 21.09.2011
      AND fcurr = p_waers    " as EUR
      AND tcurr = lv_waers.  " as TRY
```

as i said; with these conditions se16n->tcurr table turns me one row, but select statement turns me an empty row. Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: Can't the problem be connected to the date format? It should not be "21.09.2011", but "20110921" ---
SE16N performs internal/external formatting, so it shows 21.09.2011, but in plain ABAP you need to use internal format.

Comment: do u know which conversion function does this job?

Comment: when i am debugging in report i see my date variable as '21092011' so it should bring the row back.

Comment: If you're seeing 21092011 then something is not correct.  It should be 20110921.  How is p_budat defined on your selection screen?  What is the default format for dates in your user profile?

Comment: i didnt say that i see 21092011 :)
I send p_budat as 21.09.2011. p_budat is type in budat.
It turns me 79889078. In select statement i gave this number and it turned me the right record.

Comment: Yes you did?  in the comment right above mine...  "when i am debugging in report i see my date variable as '21092011' so it should bring the row back. "

Comment: sorry Brian i changed the code after i write you the comment. thats why i answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CONVERT DATE p_budat INTO INVERTED-DATE gv_date." solution :)
SELECT ukurs
INTO gs_tcurr-ukurs
FROM tcurr
WHERE kurst = p_kurst
  AND gdatu = gv_date
  AND fcurr = p_waers
  AND tcurr = lv_waers.
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the right solution ? How did you get 21.09.2011 in the first place ? If your SAP runs in multiple countries, date formats can be different per country.

Comment: i am getting record that i want with this solution :)
'convert date' gives you a number which tcurr table gets it as 21092011

Comment: If this is a "solution" of your "problem", you have a larger issue somewhere else in your code.

Comment: i was just trying to read a record in Tcurr table and problem was about date.
CONVERT DATE p_budat INTO INVERTED-DATE gv_date. gives me a number and with this number Tcurr understand which record it should give back. I didn't change anything else.

Comment: @vwegert actually it seems the code is valid. Name of the data element is GDATU_INV based on domain DATUM_INV which has has as description "Inverted date". A quick look at the content of TCURR confirms that the dates are stored in this hare brained manner.